# how can I calculate square root in 'C' at build-time?

Tags: c, math, build

I have build-time array:
const float my_array = {  blah, blah, PROXIMITY_WIDTH_PIXELS, blah,
      blah, PROXIMITY_WIDTH_PIXELS * 10.0, blah  };

I get error "initializer is not a constant" for:

```
#define    PROXIMITY_OBJECT_SIZE_PIXELS    <a constant value>
#define   PROXIMITY_WIDTH_PIXELS( sqrt( PROXIMITY_OBJECT_SIZE_PIXELS ))
```

How can I calculate square-root at build-time within a 'C' constant (build-time) array or in a #define macro  ?

Comment: How about using the infamous Fast Inverse Square Root constant, and then dividing 1 by the result? This could probably be made to work at compile-time, but it could be inaccurate...

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be a compile-time constant?  How do you define PROXIMITY_OBJECT_SIZE_PIXELS at compile time?  The C preprocessor does integer arithmetic.  Do you want the result truncated, rounded up, or what?

Comment: I normally use a calculator.

Comment: Why do you think you need that value?

Comment: This is possible.  More detail as [requested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049208/how-can-i-calculate-square-root-in-c-at-build-time#comment53919358_33049208)  How accurate?, integer?

Answer (score 2):

Using only the C preprocessor with no other code-generating tricks, you can't.

The simplest solution is to use a global variable of type `double` which is initialized before use. Unfortunately, the compiler can't be told that this is `const`, so it might generate more accesses to the variable than you might like, which may or may not matter.

If you use C++, you can do this:

```
// function calls allowed in file scope initializers!
const double proximity_width_pixels = sqrt(PROXIMITY_OBJECT_SIZE_PIXELS);
```

"Code generating tricks" refers to doing something like running a script at build time (or even a C program compiled for the build machine) time which generates a header file, into which it interpolates your floating-point constants.

Answer (score 0):

If the PROXIMITY OBJECT SIZE macro always takes one of two or three known values then maybe you can just define the PROXIMITY WIDTH PIXELS macro on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

`sqrt` is a function, thus its' result is not constant. You could use a tool like autoconf (or make your own, by compiling a simple class that uses the constant `PROXIMITY_OBJECT_SIZE_PIXELS` to generate a header you can include). This is an example of using bootstrapping to solve the chicken and egg problem. I suggest you review [Bootstrapping (Compilers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29#The_chicken_and_egg_problem) for some possible alternatives.